# SelectizeInput does not display all choices on shiny.io

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have a shiny app that has a `selectizeInput` widget which gets its about 26000 choices from a remote database in form of reactive data.
The use of a remote database and reactivity is to avoid lagging and slowness when loading the choices.
The issue is that when launched on the desktop locally, it works fine but when uploaded on shinyapps.io the widget does not present to the user all available choices.
I have played around with the widgets attributes to no avail, for example, setting **`SERVER =TRUE`** and so on.
I have put the code I am using below as well as a link to the data I want loaded to the `selectizeInput` as choices.

**UI part**

```
 library(shiny)
 library(DBI)
 library(RMySQL)
 library(shinydashboard)
 library(shinyjs)

 ui <- dashboardPage(  
     skin="yellow",  
   dashboardHeader(   ), 

  #sidebar content
   dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(  

          selectInput(
            inputId="selectData",
             label=" ", selected = NULL,
             choices=c( "title" )),      

       menuItem("Titles Search", tabName = "Titles", icon = icon("font"))

        )
       ),

     dashboardBody(

         tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML("
                  .content-wrapper {
                  background-color: green !important;
                  }

                  .main-header {
                  background-color: red !important;
                  }

                  "))

        ),

   tabItems(      
      tabItem(tabName = "Titles",              
            fluidRow(
               column(width=3,                        
                    box(                         
                      title=" ",
                       solidHeader=TRUE,
                        collapsible=TRUE,
                     width=NULL,
                     selectizeInput('titles', label = "Search by title", 
                choices = NULL, options = list(
                       placeholder = 'Type the title', maxOptions = 1000, 
                maxItems = 100,multiple = F, searchConjunction = 'and')),
                     tags$style(type="text/css",
                                ".selectize- 
        input::after{visibility:hidden;};"
                     )

                   )
                )
                )
             )                  
         )   
        )
        )
```

**Server part**

```
    library(shiny)
    library(DBI)
    library(RMySQL)
    library(shinydashboard)
    library(shinyjs)


      shinyServer(function(input, output, session) { 

        con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user='XXXX', 
                 port = 3306, password='XXXXX', 
                 dbname='XXXXXX', 
                 host='XXXXXXXX' )
           query <- function(...) dbGetQuery(con, ...)
          on.exit(dbDisconnect(con), add = TRUE)



selectedData <- reactiveValues()

observeEvent(input$selectData, {

  con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user='XXXXXX', port = 3306, password='XXXX', dbname='XXXXX', host='XXXXXXX' )
  query <- function(...) dbGetQuery(con, ...)
  on.exit(dbDisconnect(con), add = TRUE)

  if (input$selectData == "title") {
    selectedData$titledata <- query("SELECT titles FROM titles ;")
  }

  updateSelectizeInput(session, "titles",
                       choices =  as.character(unique(selectedData$titledata$titles)),
                       server = TRUE)
})

  session$onSessionEnded(function() { dbDisconnect(con) })

 })
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it a shinyapps.io problem or a coding issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are encountering a limit to the number of items selectize will load. You appear to load about 1000 items.

If you view the selectize documentation [here](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md), there is an option `maxOptions` that defaults to 1000. You even set this value equal to 1000 in your UI. Your default dataset contains 25k+ options.

- Try raising this number to 30k.
- Try adding this option to `updateSelectizeInput` in your server too.

Comment: I had tried to increase the `maxOptions` to 26000 previously in my trials but I didn't realize I  use this argument in the `SERVER` side. When I use this it now works.

Comment: To be clear, make sure you nest it inside the options parameter as such: options=list(maxOptions=20000).